# Are Custom Dimensions for YouTube Videos Possible?

Tags: webvideos

I'm creating a video that will display in a specific zone on our home page that is not a standard 16:9 dimension, (it's 1920x539, shorter from top to bottom than usual).

Is there a way to embed this into the homepage without seeing the added black bars on top and bottom?

I entered the video's actual dimensions of 1920x539 in the embed code HTML copied from YouTube, but, while the thumbnail displayed perfectly filling up the 1920x539 space, once you hit the play button, the video displays shrunken down with lots of black space around the ages.

Any tips?

(I know I can host the video myself, but I'm hoping to benefit from YouTube's handling of automatically providing the proper bitrate to users on slow connections, which our audience is likely to have.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, videos with custom dimensions are possible and are displayed without black bars in the embedded player.

I have just tested the same and it worked for me. I think the issue is with your video. In my case, there was no need to enter the actual dimensions, the copied embed-code already had it in there. If you see different dimensions I'd say something went wrong during exporting or uploading to YouTube. Maybe the wrong dimensions are stored in metadata, maybe black bars were hard-coded into the video. It's hard to say without more details of your workflow.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Matt.  Yes, you were correct, I had spaced out during the export and used a standard preset, so, though the composition settings were 1920x539, the exported file was, of course, 1920x1080.  Brain fart.  Thanks again for responding and shedding some light on the matter.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.